# Python: filename matching using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file-handling

I have written this code

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import re

now = datetime.now() 
filename = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M") #For example 202006191839

for fname in os.listdir(downloadPath):                
   if re.match('export_' + filename + '[0-9]{2}.xlsx', fname):
      print(fname)
```

In downloadPath I have these files

- export_20200619183900.xlsx
- export_20200619183921.xlsx
- export_20200619183930.xlsx

But the re.match is not matching as desired.

But, if i change

`filename = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")`

with a simple assignment

`filename = "202006191839"`

The code works.
The problem is, I need to have dynamic data.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Errrr, `datetime.now()` gives your current, local time. Are you sure you have a file with this timestamp? It will change every time you run your script.

Comment: Yes, the file is download in the same procedure, a few seconds earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

I am solved the problem... i am blind probably
The file I search, is download before the above code, despite being very small, the search command starts before the download...
I have add a simple time.sleep(2) before search command.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are matching `'export_' + filename`, but you said the file was **excel_**20200619183900

Comment: No no, I am sorry, the file is export_xxxxxxxx.
I was wrong to write in the post!